# spark out of memory error while saving data in mongoDB for large data set 1.8 TB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to save data in MongoDB using the code mentioned below for MongoDB and saving the same data as JSON in AWS s3. while the s3 write works correctly the MongoDB is giving me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, not sure what the issue is as the same data is processed in both cases for MongoDB writing and for writing the file as JSON in s3.

MongoDB write

```
mongo_format = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource"
db_url = config.get("collections").get(collection)
dataframe.write.format(mongo_format).mode("append").option("uri", db_url).save()
```

write in s3

```
path = config["input"]["logs"]["ui"] + collection
logger.info("collection " + collection + ", path: " + path)
dataframe.write.mode('append').json(path)
```

the write-in s3 is just for testing purposes ultimate goal here is to write dataframe directly in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing to the external database (MongoDB), you need a JDBC to connect between Spark and Database. Based on the code you provided, you didn't configure any connection property and all parameters are using the default value. Therefore, when you write a large dataset into MongoDB, the spark application will only use a single executor to handle this action. In such case, it has no doubt that `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` will be triggered.

When you check the JDBC configuration in Spark (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), you can try to modify the value of `numPartitions`, `batchsize`, `lowerBound` and `upperBound` to improve your performance and increase parallelism.

Although it's related to RDBMS, you can check this blog and it might give you some hints: https://luminousmen.com/post/spark-tips-optimizing-jdbc-data-source-reads

Comment: Jonathan Thanks for checking this and answering. I tried above approve however I am still getting memory issue with only mongodb. I tried to keep the numPartitions equal to spark.executor.instances which in my case is 600

Comment: @DeepakPoojari Could you share more about: 1. What is your spark version? 2. What is your driver and executor configuration? 3. How's your dataframe partitioned before writing? 4. Could you check your failed stage detail and how's your metric?

Comment: my data is stored in s3 in form of 128GB and I am reading this files using pyspark read file. I guess it is already partitioned and runs in parallel and I believe the same partitons are proceed parallely and stored in mongodb and s3.

Comment: its 128MB above